# Strip special characters and space of a DB column to compare in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 types of **last_name**:

- "Camp Bell"
- "CAMPBELL"
- "CampBellJr."
- "camp bell jr."

Now, in rails when an user is searched by it's last name like `camp bell`, I want to show all the 4 records. So, I tried:

**RAILS**

```
stripped_name = params[last_name].gsub(/\W/, '')
#=> "campbell"

User.where("LOWER(REPLACE(last_name, '/\W/', '')) LIKE ?", "#{stripped_name}%")
```

Give me only 2 records with following **last_name**:

- "CAMPBELL"
- "CampBellJr."

I guess, this is because, the mysql **REPLACE** is not working correctly with regex.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Guys, sorry for the confusion. My idea is to strip off all special characters including space. So I'm trying to use `\W` regex.

For example, the input can be: `camp~bell..`. But, it should still fetch result.

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS: `LIKE '#{stripped_name}%'`** -- You've just created a [potential SQL injection vulnerability](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection). What happens if a user enters `params[last_name] = '"; DROP TABLE users;--"` In this case, you *might* (?) get away with it, because of the `gsub`... But don't risk it, and don't leave code in a dangerous state where it could easily *become* a critical security hole.

Comment: *Always* parameterise your SQL statements. Use: `"... LIKE ?", "#{stripped_name}%"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: Maybe you could use `ILIKE` to avoid using `LOWER()`, I think it would be simpler to read. (only if you're using postgres, thx @TomLord)

Comment: @Francois This question was about `mysql`. `ILIKE` is only available in `postgresql`.

Comment: Oupsie, my bad!

Comment: `REPLACE` won’t work with regexp, but what is basically wrong with replacing spaces explicitly `LOWER(REPLACE(last_name, ' ', ''))`?!

Comment: @mudasobwa It's not only spaces. `\W` is expected to remove any special character including spaces.

Comment: I sorta know. What do you expect there, save for spaces, dots and probably commas? Do three nested REPLACEs

Comment: @mudasobwa Ok, I get your point. Although the logic would break if it's any special char. other than `.`, `,` and `space`.

Comment: @mudasobwa The purpose is to prevail search even if user has accidentally inserted any special char.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for both `stripped_name` without space and ones that include both names seperated with space like this.

```
stripped_name = params[last_name].gsub(/\W/, '')
split_names = params[last_name].split(" ")

User.where('name LIKE ? OR (name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?)', "%#{stripped_name}%", "%#{split_names[0]}%", "%#{split_names[1]}%")
```

Next step would to search for complete array of split names not just first two.

Comment: `#{%split_names[1]%}` has a couple of errors: 1. it is not valid ruby code and throws an exception, 2. it basically matches “Camp Bell” against “Belly Bellman.”

Comment: I forgott the quotation marks and put `%` in the wrong place, edited the answer. This is correct: `User.where('name LIKE ? OR (name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?)', "%#{stripped_name}%", "%#{split_names[0]}%", "%#{split_names[1]}%")`

Comment: Still matches Belly Belltone.

Comment: Everything works fine just checked in the console. Search for “Camp Bell” only returns "Camp Bell” even if "Belly Bellman" exists. You have to have have braces arount this statement just before OR `(name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?)` that's important

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
User.where("REPLACE(last_name, ' ', '') ILIKE  CONCAT ('%', REPLACE('?', ' ', ''),'%')", stripped_name)
```

`ILIKE` is like `LIKE` but the `I` is for insensitive case.

To understand easily step by step:

- `lastname ILIKE '%campbell%` you need `%` because you want lastname
  contain this string, not necessary at the begin or the end of you
  string.

  - `'campbell%'` => search string who begin by `campbell`
  - `'%campbell'` => search string who finish by `campbell`
- We need generate `'%campbell%`, so we use `CONCAT` for that
- I just use a simply `REPLACE`, but maybe you should use a regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a misunderstanding. I use `\W` so as to strip any special character including space. It's not only `space`. I have edited the question.

Comment: I just saw that you use mysql, so you right to use LOWER instead ILIKE, thanks Tom Lord